# Open file dialog in Dynamics CRM using Subgrid button

Tags: documents, dynamics-crm-2016

I've a custom entity in on-premise environment of Dynamics CRM 2016, namely `Documents`. Also, I've placed a sub-grid that on accounts form to add documents. Now, I want to open the file dialog using the system button of that subgrid.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does file dialog mean "create new" dialog? And does system button mean the + button?

Comment: no, browse new file and using using '+' button

Comment: still not following, maybe post a screenshot

Comment: well, I want to open the file dialog using '+' button of subgrid in dynamics crm order form